# О происхождении слова «оказия»

Tags: значение-слов, этимология

Каково происхождение и значение данного слова? Почему перестало употребляться и чем заменилось?

Comment: См. http://etymological.academic.ru/3261 и http://gallicismes.academic.ru/26758/%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Не знал, что оно не употребляется.

Comment: В живой речи практически нет.

Comment: @slava1947 Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: _Nicolas Chabanovsky: @slava1947 Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы..._ === Развёрнутый ответ по приведённому выше вопросу доверяю написать Вам. А для подсказки же в комментариях вполне допустима, на мой взгляд,   и просто ссылка на соответствующие статьи.

Answer (score 1):

Оказия — случай, (заимств. в XVII в из польск. яз. , где okazja «случай» (от лат. occasio суф. производного от occidere «падать» ). **У Черных:**  В русском языке известно с начала XVIII века, в словарях - с 1782 года. Возможно, заимствовано из латинского языка.

**Значения слова:**

1) **Удобный, благоприятный** случай. Послать письмо с оказией. Хоть раненько задумал ты жениться, да зато Марья Ивановна такая добрая барышня, Что грех и пропустить оказию! Пушкин.

2) **Редкий, из ряда вон выходящий случай** (разг.) . — Что за оказия! Молчалин, ты, брат? Грибоедов. Эка оказия сталась! Вот оказия: мост провалился!

**Комментарий (почему перестало употребляться и чем заменилось)**

Слово «оказия» в первом значении устарело (послать письмо с оказией, пропустить оказию), во втором значении практически тоже мало используется, так как заменяется синонимами. Курьез – смешной случай, казус – сложный, затруднительный, необычный случай, инцидент – неприятный случай, недоразумение.

В разговорном стиле можно использовать слова история, приключение. Как сказать на современном языке: «Вот оказия: мост провалился»?  Скорее всего, найдутся разные междометия.

Можно еще добавить, что два значения слова "оказия", скорее, **противоречат друг другу:** с одной стороны, благоприятный случай, с другой - редкий и, возможно,  не очень приятный или желательный. Это также могло стать причиной того, что слово редко используется в языке.

Comment: Не могу сказать, что во втором значении тоже перестает употреблятся. А откуда такая информация?

Comment: А что, Вы часто говорите: "Вот оказия! Что за оказия!"? Да и  со времен Булгакова язык вполне мог измениться. Также можно вспомнить о применении  устаревших слов, которые могут использоваться в художественном тексте для указания на время действия или  выполнять  стилистические функции, являться выразительными средствами.

Comment: Это не аргумент. Я многих слов вообще не употребляю, словарный запас каждого индивидума ограничен от силы 10 тыс. слов, из которых в активном употреблении 2-3 тысячи. Что ж, остальные устарели? Впрочем, вполне могу сказать и "что за оказия!", ибо грибоедовский текст мне хорошо знаком. Может просто по жизни таких ситуаций не встречается, чтобы такую фразу вызвать. Нет, надо ориентироваться все-таки на орфоэпические словари, а через них - ко всем массе носителей. Тогда что-то объективное можно сформулировать.

Comment: Грибоедовским текстом Вы просто украсите  свою речь или соотнесете свою ситуацию с грибоедовскими героями. О такой функции устаревших слов уже говорилось. К тому же вариант назван не устаревшим, а устаревающим, то есть частотность его употребления в современном языке заметно снижена.

Answer (score 0):

У слова оказия в современном языке два значения. Сьтарое (=случай, возможность) действительно выходит из употребления (а зачем оно, когда есть просто "случай"?) и используется больше в шутливом, ироничном стиле.
А вот второе - в ходу вполне.

Значение

> 1. разг. удобный, благоприятный случай для посылки, отправки чего-либо с кем-либо ◆ Спустя месяц, уж не помню, с какой оказией, мне
>      привезли загадочную огромную коробку. Сати Спивакова, «Не всё», 2002
>      г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список
>      литературы)
> 2. непредвиденный, редкий, из ряда вон выходящий случай; неожиданность ◆ И, собственно говоря, открылся передо мною мир, в
>      который я стремился, и вот такая оказия, что он мне показался сразу же
>      нестерпимым. М. А. Булгаков, «Театральный роман», 1937 г. (цитата из
>      Национального корпуса русского языка, см. Список литературы)

(Вики)

Посему надо договориться сначала, о каком значении вопрос.